# Convert string to object.property in Typescript?

Tags: string, typescript, object

How do I convert a string from example: 'person.name' to an object property - person.name?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use **JSON.parse(obj)** ;

1)create model
export class Person{
  name:string;
  age :number;
}

2) getting your response string 

 res="{"name":"john","age":22}" ;

3)create object 
  person :Person ;

4)this.person= <Person> JSON.parse(this.res);
```